# how to step down both voltage and current for high power

Tags: voltage-divider, high-voltage, current-limiting, high-current

I have looked at Buck converters, voltage dividers, and current dividers, but I have not found a way to divide, BOTH, voltage AND current + being able to do it over high voltages and currents.

- With voltage dividers, voltage is divided, but current remains the same.
- With current dividers, current is divided but voltage remains the same.
- With buck converters (as far as I know), the voltage goes down, but the current goes up.

**How do I efficiently divide both voltage and current over high power?**

#### EDIT:

**I don't want to be limited to dividing the voltage and current equally, I just need to be able to divide both.**

This is for a 14lb robot. I have 4 Battery packs for each of my Wheel Motors. I want to connect them in series, then step down the voltage and current down to a voltage/current that an Arduino can handle.

I have 48v, 80A power. I want to divide the voltage by 10.7, and at the same time, divide the current by 2670 resulting in 4.5v, 30mA for the Arduino board.

***Please answer with a simple schematic diagram with your post.***

Comment: Try to skip the theory and pre-supposed solutions and rather describe exactly what you're trying to do and why, because what you've got here just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Buck or boost converters pass power (voltage times current), so if you step the voltage down, the available current will increase.  If you supply the required voltage to a load, it will only draw the current it requires, regardless of how much the power source can provide.

Comment: you are not understanding how current relates to voltage

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or a practical one? Are you trying to power something specific? If so, please edit your question to include information about what you are trying to power, including a link to the product information page or datasheet or what have you. In general, the power supply does not have freedom to set both voltage and current. The typical supply sets either voltage or current, and then the load decides on how to set the free variable. There are exceptions. But it is NEVER the case that the supply can dictate both voltage and current to the load. They negotiate.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings

Comment: "How do I efficiently divide both voltage and current equally with over 2,300-3,000 Watts of power?"  by moving to another universe.  In *this* universe, energy (and, hence, power) is conserved, and electrical energy = current * voltage.  So if you start with 3200W and divide both voltage and current by a factor of four, you're left with 200W -- and the other 3000W are going toward burning up your power supply.

Comment: If you want to get X volts and Y amperes from a power source that's *rated* at 4X volts and 4Y amperes, that's a different story -- but you have to explain what you really want.

Comment: F=ma If mass is the load, you can regulate force or you can regulate acceleration but you can't regulate both. Same idea.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question. It is somewhat clearer now. Your best bet will be to power your arduino from a buck converter. The arduino is designed to run from a fixed voltage. The current will vary based on what the arduino is doing and you need to make sure you can supply as much as it needs. But you don't need to "step down" the current. Just step-down the voltage.

Comment: @mkeith , So you are saying that, by reducing the voltage using a buck converter, The output current will be reduced also. Is that right? Also, an Arduino's "absolute max current" rating is 40mA. Seeing that the ratio of voltage to current is almost 1:2, are you sure that I don't have to worry about the current coming from the buck converter?

Comment: If the arduino only needs 30mA or 40mA, find a buck rated for 50 mA to 100 mA. That is all you have to worry about as far as current goes. A larger buck that can supply 1 or 2 Amps wouldn't do any harm, but it is not needed. Most things other than LED's want to be powered by a fixed voltage. They decide how much current they need. LED's are a little different. Totally raw LED's with no resistors or driver should be driven by a current source. But let's not get into that, I guess.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings should answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get power for you Arduino from the 48 Volt battery bank, you just need a buck converter or DC-DC converter to convert the 48 volts to 5 volts.  The converter just needs to be able to supply at least the maximum current that the Arduino and any other 5 volt loads require.

If you select a DC-DC converter that is only rated to deliver 100 mA, that will be the maximum current you can draw from it, regardless of the original battery's voltage and current rating.

The 5 volt loads will only draw whatever current they require – a converter rated for 5 V 100 mA output will not force 100 mA into the loads.

Consider the electric outlets in your home – you can plug a 1000 Watt heater or a 15 Watt night light into the same outlet with no special precautions – each device will only draw the power or current that it requires.

Comment: Of course! Silly me! As long as the Arduino is not directly connected to the wires carrying the 20A load, I don't have to worry about current.

Comment: @Circuit-B0ARD - Incorrect. Or at least, that does not make sense. I can connect a device that needs 12v and consumes 100mA (1.2 Watts) to a car-battery. A power-source capable of supplying the 1300 W needed to run the starter motor. The ECU is also connected to the battery..... Match the voltages, then ensure the device consumes less current than you can supply. The concept of dividing current as you appear to grasp it is entirely, completely wrong. Think of current as liters of water a second. If you can supply more than you need, you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2,300W-3000W of power and you want to both divide voltage and current, then you will no longer have 2,300W-3000W of power. P = IV, thus you cannot lower both voltage and current while maintaining the same amount of power. For example, if you have a conversion of 50V at 60A you have (50V)(60A) = 3kW of power, converting it to 25V at 15A gives you 375W of power.

I'm assuming you're asking this question because you have some 50V, 60A power supply. In this case if the system you're supplying power to needs 25V at 15A, simply convert the 50V to 25V, the impedance of the system you're powering if rated for 25V will then only draw the 15A it needs so there is most likely no need to add additional components to reduce current.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s round it up to 60V @ 60A for available power.
This means power is 3.6kW to 1 Ohm

Next you wanted to use all that power 4 ways.

30V @ 15A which is each 450W to 30/15= 2 ohms.

The load must be regulated to this effective resistance to achieve 2 Ohms minimum with a buck converter or bipolar battery system to achieve either 0,30,60 with 30 being common or +/-30V and no less than 2Ohms DCR to not exceed its share.